# Convert cURL call to Java

Tags: java, rest, curl, get, httpclient

I have the following cURL that I want to convert to java code:

```
curl -i -b 'JSESSIONID=ekl23l2-3321-1930-b889-kelwek23b8v9; Path=/; HttpOnly' http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/library
```

In the above call, JSESSIONID cookie is responsible for making sure that the server authenticates the call. I came up with the following Java code:

```
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/library");
    httpGet.addHeader("Set-Cookie","JSESSIONID=ekl23l2-3321-1930-b889-kelwek23b8v9; Path=/; HttpOnly");
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    JSONObject o = new JSONObject(result.toString());
    rd.close();
    httpClient.close();
```

However, this doesn't work for me as the server complains of unauthorized access. This response happens when user is not authorized, which means that somehow the JSESSIONID is not getting properly setup. Can anyone comment if this is the proper way to translate the cURL to Java?

Comment: Have you tried looking your web server log files? Snooped the HTTP traffic over the interface? Sometimes when things like that fail it can be a very nuanced things that shows up in the sniffed headers that tells you what flag or feature you might need to set. Can you update your question with the curl HTTP  packet sent  and the Java packet sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Set-Cookie` (that comes from server in response header) whereas it should be only `Cookie:` (goes from client in request header).

```
httpGet.addHeader("Cookie","JSESSIONID=ekl23l2-3321-1930-b889-kelwek23b8v9; Path=/; HttpOnly");
```